# Regex require certain ending on string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following three strings:

```
>>> s_no = '¥2,571'
>>> s_yes = '$2,57'
>>> s_yes = '2,57 $'
```

How would I construct a regex to match only the second one? The one I am using so far is:

```
re.search(r'\,\d{2}[\s|$]?',s) # should start on a comma. Unconcerned what comes before it.
```

Basically I want it to allow a (1) comma -- (2) then two digits -- (3) then either the end of the string or a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> tgt="""\
... >>> s_no = '¥2,571
... >>> s_yes = '$2,57
... >>> s_yes = '2,57 $"""
```

You can use the pattern `,\d\d(?: |$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF2mC3/2)

Python:

```
>>> re.findall(r',\d\d(?: |$)', tgt, flags=re.M)
[',57', ',57 ']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please explain the usage of the `re.M` flag in the above?

Comment: `re.M` is for the [multiline flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) so that the `^` and `$` regex meta characters match the beginning of logical lines versus only at the beginning and end of a string. It is only required in the example here because `tgt` is three logical lines and `$` would only match at the very end of the string without it.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got most of it, but you want to make sure that you don't use a character set `[]`. Instead, use a capture group `()`. If you want to get either the end of the string, or a space and then the end of the string, you want `(\s$|$)`. Putting it together: `r'\,\d{2}(\s$|$)'`

There are plenty of websites (like regexr.com) where you can put in any regex, and it automatically highlights the text. It usually helps me out in the rare case I use regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
dollar_sign = r"\$"
dollars = r"(?P<dollars>\d+)"
cents = r"(?:,(?P<cents>\d{2}))?"
amount_re = r"^" + dollar_sign + dollars + cents + r"\s*$"

m = re.search(amount_re, "$2,57 ")

print("Got", m.group('dollars'), "dollars", end='')
print(m.group('cents') if m.group('cents') is not None else "even")
```